# Another term or synonym for 'safer appoach'

Tags: phrase-request

what can I write other words in place of "safer approach" that will appear nice to read as title.
Context: xyz  a "safer approach for the therapy".

Answer (score 1):

Usually

> a safer approach

to doing something might be described as

> a conservative approach
>   a traditional approach
>   a well-known approach
>   a time-honored approach

all four have the implied meaning that the "approach" being used has been tested and used over a longer period of time.  In contrast to

> a radical approach
>   a new approach
>   an innovative approach

Neither set of descriptions implies whether an approach is "correct" or will work only whether is might have been observed to work.